# is it possible to save the api response into sharedpreferences inside the login function?

Tags: android, flutter, sharedpreferences

can anyone please help me?, I created a login function with api, when the user wants to login and succeeds then it is directed to the profilescreen the user details appear, but when it switches to the homescreen and switches to the profilescreen again, the user details that previously appeared are lost and become null.

I thought of using sharedpreferences to save user response data after login, but I don't know if it was saved or not

```
Future<LoginModels> postLogin(String email, String password) async {
var dio = Dio();
String baseurl = url;

Map<String, dynamic> data = {'email': email, 'password': password};
try {
  final response = await dio.post(
    '$baseurl/api/login',
    data: data,
    options: Options(headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'}),
  );
  print('Respon -> ${response.data} + ${response.statusCode}');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final loginModel = LoginModels.fromJson(response.data);
    return loginModel;
  }
} catch (e) {
  print('Error di $e');
}
return LoginModels();}
```

i tried adding sharedpreference in the part after response.statuscode == 200 , like this

```
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String jsonUser = jsonEncode(loginModel);
    pref.setString('userDetail', jsonUser);
    print('data nih $jsonUser');
```

and the output is like this
[image: (from api (Respon -> {...})) and (i tried sharedpreferences (Data nih {...}))]

```
LoginModels loginModelsFromJson(String str) => LoginModels.fromJson(
  json.decode(str),
);

String loginModelsToJson(LoginModels data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class LoginModels {
  LoginModels({
   this.isActive,
   this.message,
   this.data,
});
  bool? isActive;
  String? message;
  Data? data;

factory LoginModels.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => LoginModels(
  isActive: json["is_active"],
  message: json["message"],
  data: Data.fromJson(json["data"]),
);
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
  "is_active": isActive,
  "message": message,
  "data": data?.toJson(),
  };
}
class Data {
  Data({
   this.iduser,
   this.nama,
   this.profesi,
   this.email,
   this.password,
   this.roleId,
   this.isActive,
   this.tanggalInput,
   this.modified,
 });

  String? iduser;
  String? nama;
  String? profesi;
  String? email;
  String? password;
  String? roleId;
  String? isActive;
  String? tanggalInput;
  String? modified;

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
    iduser: json["iduser"],
    nama: json["nama"],
    profesi: json["profesi"],
    email: json["email"],
    password: json["password"],
    roleId: json["role_id"],
    isActive: json["is_active"],
    tanggalInput: json["tanggal_input"],
    modified: json["modified"],
  );
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "iduser": iduser,
    "nama": nama,
    "profesi": profesi,
    "email": email,
    "password": password,
    "role_id": roleId,
    "is_active": isActive,
    "tanggal_input": tanggalInput,
    "modified": modified,
  };
}

class User {
  String? id;
  String? nama;
  String? profesi;
  String? email;
  String? password;
  String? roleId;
  String? isActive;
  String? tanggalInput;
  String? modified;

  User();

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json["iduser"],
        nama = json['nama'],
        profesi = json['profesi'],
        email = json['email'],
        password = json['password'],
        roleId = json['role_id'],
        isActive = json['is_active'],
        tanggalInput = json['tanggal_input'],
        modified = json['modified'];



Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'nama': nama,
        'profesi': profesi,
        'email': email,
        'password': password,
        'role_id': roleId,
        'is_active': isActive,
        'tanggal_input': tanggalInput,
        'modified': modified,
      };
}
```

if it is already stored how do I retrieve the data? or is there another alternative to solve the problem I have?

Answer (score 0):

you can use key-value for store in pref. if u want to save user's email,name,id than store it like this (note:this is example of GetX)

```
//to store data
var storeUserData = Get.find<SharedPreferences>();
storeUserData.setString('use_name',userName);
// to retrive data
var userName = storeUserData.getString('use_name');
```

set this userName to your profilescreen's text and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

While storing this in SharedPreferences call the toMap() method on the object This will return a Map<String, dynamic> representation of your current object.

```
Map<String, dynamic> productsMap = products.toMap();
```

After that Convert the object to String by using json.encode() and store it !

```
storedCart(productsMap){
     SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefs.setString('userData', json.encode(productsMap));
}
```

you'll notice that when we convert our object to JSON it becomes a big String, Therefore it is possible for us to store it in SharedPreferences using the "putString()" method.

Also you can store single single value store in SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString("user", token);
```

Also When you want to get data from sharedPref
you have to call

```
var value = prefs.getString(key);
```

> After that you have to decode the value.

```
var decodeValue = json.decode(value)
final loginModel = LoginModels.fromJson(decodeValue).
```

after that you can find every data base on your model class

Comment: How to call every data if a map is made? Examples only call the name data

Comment: I have changed my answer. How you get pref value. Thank you

Comment: thanks! , I have tried to make a map and put it while sending data, and succeeded, now only ways to call if different screen

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use .apply() once you update the fields in the code.

Comment: Where should I put it?